# Unwanted Spacing between images

Tags: html, css, image, spacing

Here on [this page](http://themeforest.net/item/gfashion-responsive-magento-theme-/7688686?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=WebDezyners), in product description area, i have inserted many images. There is spacing between images which are ruining the look and feel of the description area. I've written the description area code in a separate html file, and there shows no spacing, but when i enter into this website, it shows this spacing.

Here is the code of the description area:

```
<div class="user-html">
 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_01_zpsf96f2f18.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_02_zps5735a5a8.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_03_zpsf4933cc6.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_04_zpsd74ee7ae.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_05_zps103cc79e.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_06_zps113ee0a8.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_07_zps7e7846f8.jpg" alt="\\"> 

<img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_08_zpsa14f563d.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_09_zps98ea736c.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_10_zpse05cb796.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_11_zps895af16e.jpg" alt="\\"> 

 <img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_12_zps69ebae8b.png" alt="\\">
</div>
```

Please advise how to get rid of these spaces.

**Update:** It appears that when I enter any in-line style tags within the description box area of themeforest website, it strips out all style tags. So, all the answers listed below aren't working. Any other solution?

Comment: @Medda86 The whitespace is not coming from the image margins, but from the actual whitespace in the code, which shows up for inline-block elements.

Answer (score -1):

One of the CSS tricks to get rid of the whitespace in such cases would be:

```
.user-html {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

The other one, is to avoid the `inline-block` display for images (which is the reason for the whitespaces):

```
.user-html img {
    display: block;
}
```

This will work in your case because you have one image per row, otherwise you'd have to go with the first example to eliminate the whitespace.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've indicated a problem in question update. Plz check and let me know if you know how to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure if you tried adding a style tag or inline styles to each image. Try the one you didn't try. According to their guidelines, you should be able to use some CSS: http://support.envato.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/262/41/how-do-i-format-a-post
If everything fails, you can join your images into a single image file and add it like that.

Comment: It appears everything fails, I have to show it as a single image file. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, if you have no specific reasons for cutting up images, I'd say having a single image is actually a good solution, not a fallback.

Answer (score -1):

For your case, the following will remove the space between images

```
.user-html img {
    float: left;
}
```

Tested in the page you have linked in your question

By the way the white space is present because you have space between two images tags which is rendered as empty space

You can test it by copy pasting the below code:

```
<div class="user-html"><img src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/images-photo.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/images-photo.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_03_zpsf4933cc6.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_04_zpsd74ee7ae.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_05_zps103cc79e.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_06_zps113ee0a8.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_07_zps7e7846f8.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_08_zpsa14f563d.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_09_zps98ea736c.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_10_zpse05cb796.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_11_zps895af16e.jpg" alt="\\"><img src="http://i956.photobucket.com/albums/ae49/anwartheravian/Slice_12_zps69ebae8b.png" alt="\\"></div>
```

Comment: Themeforest is stripping out all the in-line style tags i'm adding. Can you advise any way around?

Comment: Did you try copy pasting the HTML code , I have included in the answer?